# Can I find all vertices that have no connected edges in OrientDB?

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

Is there an easy way to query a cluster for all vertices that have no incoming edges?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is more complete because also covers the case the collection exists but it's empty:

```
select from the_cluster where in().size() = 0
```

Comment: should be a single `=`, though.

Comment: I just ran this query, and am getting all the vertices as the output, including those that have incoming edges. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Lvca: This one worked. Did it get changed in the newer version?

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL seems to work (as edges are stored as fields `in` and `out` on the vertices):

```
select from the_cluster where in is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it be this?

select from the_cluster where in_edgename is null

I know it's an old question but figured for anyone else who was wondering the same thing.

Comment: Please make your answer more assertive. While this looks to answer the question (and really looks like the accepted answer, actually) the **Should it be this?** make your answer more like a question to the OP and then irrelevant for an answer but belonging to a comment. If you do know the answer, state the answer, do not question it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
for a vertex of a class say Vtex and the Edge of class say Edg

select from Vtex where in('Edg').size() =0

This will return all the vertices of Vtex class which have no incoming edge of type Edg.